# How to get the correct range to set the value to a cell?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to set text or number in Google Sheet from script.

I want to set `Hello` or number `9` in cell `F2`. I found this code so far:

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().setValue('hello');
```

but that doesn't specify which cell.

Comment: may I suggest that you read the basics of appscript by trying the [tutorials ?](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles)

Answer (score 254, accepted):

The following code does what is required

```
function doTest() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('F2').setValue('Hello');
}
```

Comment: how getRange with numbers ? what are the coordinate of the c2 cell ?

Comment: C2 is third column second row so >> getRange(2,3)  >> getRange(row,col)

Answer (score 55):

Use [`setValue`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue) method of [`Range`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) class to set the value of particular cell.

```
function storeValue() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  // ss is now the spreadsheet the script is associated with
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0]; // sheets are counted starting from 0
  // sheet is the first worksheet in the spreadsheet
  var cell = sheet.getRange("B2"); 
  cell.setValue(100);
}
```

You can also select a cell using row and column numbers.

```
var cell = sheet.getRange(2, 3); // here cell is C2
```

It's also possible to set value of multiple cells at once.

```
var values = [
  ["2.000", "1,000,000", "$2.99"]
];

var range = sheet.getRange("B2:D2");
range.setValues(values);
```

Answer (score 26):

**Solution :** `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('F2').setValue('hello')`

**Explanation :**

*Setting value in a cell in spreadsheet to which script is attached*

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME).getRange(RANGE).setValue(VALUE);
```

*Setting value in a cell in sheet which is open currently and to which script is attached*

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(RANGE).setValue(VALUE);
```

*Setting value in a cell in some spreadsheet to which script is NOT attached (Destination sheet name known)*

```
SpreadsheetApp.openById(SHEET_ID).getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME).getRange(RANGE).setValue(VALUE);
```

*Setting value in a cell in some spreadsheet to which script is NOT attached (Destination sheet position known)*

```
SpreadsheetApp.openById(SHEET_ID).getSheets()[POSITION].getRange(RANGE).setValue(VALUE);
```

*These are constants, you must define them yourself*

```
SHEET_ID

SHEET_NAME

POSITION

VALUE

RANGE
```

By script attached to a sheet I mean that script is residing in the script editor of that sheet. Not attached means not residing in the script editor of that sheet. It can be in any other place.

Comment: Hi - Regarding to which a "Script is Active"

I have an INDEX/Table formula that I want in cell D18 on Worsheet 'FianceIndex'
When I do the formula in the Cell itself it doesn't auto-refresh - so I figured put it in a script and apply a trigger.

Problem with getActiveSheet() is that every other sheet gets it.

How do I fix that?
I tried "getSheetName"

    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getSheetName('FinanceIndex').getRange('D18').setValue('=Dollar(Index(ImportHTML("https://www.apmex.com/silver-price","table",8),2,2))');

I'm stuck

Comment: Try `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetName('FinanceIndex')`. Otherwise please ask a new question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask