# How do I incorporate the Google Sheets API into javascript belonging to asp.net web page?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-sheets-api

i have an ASP.Net website which saves a few numerical values to write to a google spreadsheet. My goal is to write any particular value into the active cell of the spreadsheet. I found a very helpful example [(from StackOverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41889391/set-value-of-active-cell-in-google-sheets-script), The issue is that I don't know how to reference the Google Sheets API in the javascript code I use to handle OnClientClick events.

I tried using a GitHub repository. I was able to clone the git with the GitHub extension, but I wasn't sure how to reference the files in the javascript code. I also followed the [tutorial from google](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/nodejs) to install the API using Node.js quickstart, but I'm not sure what to do after installing the client library.

Which of the two options I tried should I follow through with? And how do I reference the files in javascript?

Comment: Only a bound apps script project can be associated with an active Google Sheets UI session. Only in this session does the concept of an "active cell" exist. From a third party (such as your personal web server), you can use either the Sheets REST API (to directly work with Google Sheets content) or the Apps Script REST API to interact with Apps Script code you have written (that interacts with various Google things, Sheets included).

Comment: I don't have any apps script code. Is there any way to add google apps script to m existing asp.net site?

Comment: No, there is not. Apps Script is written here: https://script.google.com/home