# Reading a matrix of data into a script function from Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

I am new to Google Sheet script so I am trying to learn by looking at other professional code. I have noticed that most routines that read in arrays use `.getDataRange().getValues()` which reads in the whole worksheet.

The worksheets I work on have lots of different data info on any one sheet. Is there an easy way to read in a subset of the sheet and not the whole sheet?

As an example: If I want to read in range D6:J45 (note the ranges can change based on user request):

1. How can I load in only that matrix data into a 2 dimensional array in Script?
2. If I have to use nested for loops, .length seems to get me # of rows, how can get number of columns in range?

Comment: At least [read the top voted questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script?sort=votes) before posting. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set the value of a cell in Google Sheets using Apps Script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11334296/how-to-set-the-value-of-a-cell-in-google-sheets-using-apps-script)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use [getRange(a1Notation)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(String)) to get the values of the specified range.
- `getValues()` returns a 2D array. The number of columns corresponds to the length of the inner arrays, so you have to retrieve the `length` of an element of the outer array, as shown below:

```js
var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("D6:J45").getValues();
var numberOfColumns = values[0].length;
```