# I'm attempting to adapt a script to "submit" a number of cells to another sheet, which is named in cell A5

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

the spreadsheet in question - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1t50ieV8dRvvyfsYVaxf_ZthToA-60dSW6xpjBNvVvA4/edit?usp=sharing

The value in A5 indicates which sheet the data should be submitted to.

I'm new to scripting, and have found a simple bit of code that looks like it will do the trick, but because I don't understand part of it, I'm unable to adapt it to my sheet.

```
function submitData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Tool Life");
  var range = sheet.getRange(1,5)
  var data = range.getValue()
  var datasheet = ss.getSheetByName(data);
  
  //Input Values
  var values = [[sheet.getRange("B5").getValue(),   //tool
                 sheet.getRange("C5").getValue(),   //reason
                 sheet.getRange("D5").getValue(),   //replaced
                 sheet.getRange("E5").getValue(),   //current
                 sheet.getRange("F5").getValue(),   //new
                 sheet.getRange("G5").getValue(),   //from length
                 sheet.getRange("H5").getValue(),   //to length
                 sheet.getRange("I5").getValue(),   //from diameter
                 sheet.getRange("J5").getValue(),   //to diameter
                 sheet.getRange("K5").getValue(),   //where used
                 sheet.getRange("L5").getValue(),   //flagged
                 sheet.getRange("M5").getValue(),   //set to measure
                 sheet.getRange("N5").getValue(),   //name
                 sheet.getRange("O5").getValue(),   //date
                 sheet.getRange("P5").getValue()]]; //comments
                 
  
  datasheet.getRange(datasheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, 15).setValues(values);
}
```

I don't understand what the numbers are for on the last line of code.  I'm assuming the 15 is for either the number of columns, or number of entries.

I'm taking a guess that I can use the variable "data" in this line:  `var datasheet = ss.getSheetByName(data);`  but because it doesn't work, I can't play around with it.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11334296 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63720612

Answer (score 2):

### Explanation:

You are very close.

- According to the spreadsheet that you provided, you want to get cell
  **A5** of the **Tool Life** sheet. You are calling `sheet.getRange(1,5)` but that gives cell **E1**. You should use
  `sheet.getRange(5,1)` or `sheet.getRange('A5')` instead to get the correct cell.
- It is always a good idea to reference to the length of `values` instead of hardcopying the ranges. Use that instead:

  ```
  datasheet.getRange(datasheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
  ```

---

### Solution:

```
function submitData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Tool Life");
  var range = sheet.getRange(5,1);
  var data = range.getValue();
  var datasheet = ss.getSheetByName(data);
  
  //Input Values
  var values = [[sheet.getRange("B5").getValue(),   //tool
                 sheet.getRange("C5").getValue(),   //reason
                 sheet.getRange("D5").getValue(),   //replaced
                 sheet.getRange("E5").getValue(),   //current
                 sheet.getRange("F5").getValue(),   //new
                 sheet.getRange("G5").getValue(),   //from length
                 sheet.getRange("H5").getValue(),   //to length
                 sheet.getRange("I5").getValue(),   //from diameter
                 sheet.getRange("J5").getValue(),   //to diameter
                 sheet.getRange("K5").getValue(),   //where used
                 sheet.getRange("L5").getValue(),   //flagged
                 sheet.getRange("M5").getValue(),   //set to measure
                 sheet.getRange("N5").getValue(),   //name
                 sheet.getRange("O5").getValue(),   //date
                 sheet.getRange("P5").getValue()]]; //comments
                 
  
  datasheet.getRange(datasheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

---

### References:

- [getRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column)